# When does Haskell complain about incorrect typing in functions?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-mismatch, typechecking

I am a Haskell newbie trying to wrap my head around type binding in functions and how Haskell enforces it. For example, even though the type for the `fst` function is `fst :: (a, b) -> a`, the compiler does not complain for the function `fst'`. But the compiler complains about type bindings for the function `elem'`.

```
fst' :: (a,a) -> a
fst' s = fst s

elem' :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> [b] -> Bool
elem' x xs = elem x xs
```

Comment: When you use a function with incorrect types. The reason why it does not complain about the first one is because you here define a "subset" type signature, that is fine. Whereas in the latter, that is not the case.

Comment: The nicest way I've found to think about this is that you can always make a type more specific than it needs to be, but you can't always make it more general. A spoon can be used for many things, but _my_ spoon I choose to use only on ice-cream ;)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "Subset" is a poor choice of word here (which is presumably why you put it in quotes). "More restrictive" which you use in your answer is much better. The technical term is `(a, a) -> a` is an *instance* of `(a, b) -> a`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`fst` has as type [**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) so that means it is fine to define a function:

```
fst' :: (a, a) -> a
fst' = fst
```

Your `fst'` function is *more restrictive* than the `fst` function. Regardless with what you replace `a` in your `fst'` function that is fine for `fst`. If for example `a ~ Bool` holds, then you call `fst` with signature `fst :: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool`. But since `fst` can deal with all `a`s and `b`, it is fine that both elements of the tuple are `Bool`, so given `fst` can handle tuples for all possible types for both the first and the second item of the 2-tuple, it is defintely ok if the two items have the same type.

The latter is *not* ok, here you define:

```
elem' :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> [b] -> Bool
elem' = elem
```

but `elem` has type [**`elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:elem). The signatures you can make with the `elem'` function are not a subset of the ones of the `elem` function, since you can set `a ~ Int` and `b ~ Bool`. In that case you expect `elem :: Int -> [Bool] -> Bool`, but evidently that does not hold, since the `Int` and `Bool` type are two different types, and in the `elem` signature, these are both `a`s.

Comment: Covers everything, nothing to add here, I wanted to answer adding something. But usually your answers are very good and complete.